# C# cellphone Message retrieval functionality

Tags: c#

Is there a way to write C# code that can access phone root and retrieve all messages,deleted or undeleted?And how do you trace a phone by it's geolocation using c# code?...

Comment: you need to check cell phone provider SDK.

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is rather too broad and will trigger only a difuse discussion. This is not what SO is good for. Have a look at [the asking help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Can you tell me what kind of answer you expect to get to this question? "Is there a way to write C# code that ..." the answer would be "Yes", would that satisfy you? "how do you trace a phone by it's geolocation" what do you expect? a description of the algorithm? the necessary technology? the entire code?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up,I was looking for sample code that does that functionality.Retrieval of messages and locating a cellphone device.

Comment: sorry to disappoint you mate but you need to specify a little more your problem. SO expects more. Question that simply ask for sample code will not be answered and rather closed as too broad.